# Fitting a MotoGadget V2 Unit on my motorbike

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, fuel-system, wiring

I have an older fuel injected motorbike (Ducati 2003 DS1000 SSie) which I would like to customise. I am planning on fitting a MotoGadget V2 Unit, to simplify the wiring.

On this unit, there are in- and outputs for most standard accessories on the bike (horn, lights, starter, indicators). There is also an AUXILIARY output, where, as they say, everything else should be connected. They mean the ignition (coils) AND other accessories which they not specify.

In the case of my bike, there are a lot of other "sensors" as well as other things which need electricity and send a signal to the central processing unit (ECU), in order for the fuel injection to work properly!

According to Motogadget, "*If more than two cables should connected to AUX outlet all necessary cables have to be combined with a external terminal*"

The unit: [MotoGadget V2](http://motogadget.com/shop/en/m-unit-digit-tastersteuerung-u-sicherung.html)
The manual (pdf): [Manual](http://motogadget.com/shop/media/downloads/manual/munit_v2_manual_en_3.2_k.pdf)

**QUESTION**: What do they mean "an external terminal"? They mean ONE WIRE which (somehow) feeds **ALL SENSORS** AND POSSIBLY OTHER THINGS (**FUEL PUMP** is one that comes to mind) with electricity? Is there a proper "thing" which does this? Is there a possible problem with OVERLOAD?

(I have asked this question at Motogadget, and, since I have not bought the thing yet, they said they cannot help me!!! And none of the car-electricians I asked can give me a proper answer to satisfy me (that he knows what he is talking about. There is also no further help in the manual.)

THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what they mean by this is they don't want you stuffing 1/2 a dozen wires into the distribution block on the same connector. Instead, they want you to put one wire into the distribution block (the MotoGadget V2 thing), then connect your multiple connections to the single wire coming out of the block. This would only be if you have multiple connections which need to go to the same port on the MotoGadget.

You'd need to somehow connect your multiple wires (connections) onto the single wire ... that's whatever plan you come up with to make it work. Could be some other kind of distribution block or what have you. If you don't have any multi-leads which need to go into a single port, then don't worry about it. At least, this is my take on it.

Comment: Yes, most probably you are right. My worry is, how many "auxiliaries" can potentially be fed from this one wire? I can think of the Fuel Pump, the Clock lamps and3 or 4 sensors, plus maybe a real auxiliary (GPS or similar). WOuld there be a problem with the load? Is there a limit?